# How to apply a filter between two date column in powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a column name start date and another column name is end date. Now I want to create a filter between min of start date and max of end date in powerbi

```
Start date      End date
1/12/2024      6/12/2024
```

In filter pane there is no option to do that. We have to create some measures

Answer (score 0):

In the Filter pane, you can select `Advanced filtering` and then set the date with `is on or after` or `is on or before`, for each of the two date columns.

[image]

You can also achieve the same with a Measure similar to this one:

```
Count between dates =
  CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('Your Table'),
    'Your Table'[Start date] >= DATE(2024, 12, 1) &&
    'Your Table'[Enddate] <= DATE(2024, 12, 6)
  )
```

Then add this measure as to the `Filters on this visual` section in the Filters pane, and set it to `is not blank`.